# XTerm: Bitmap font for ASCII, TrueType font for Unicode

Tags: unicode, xterm, ascii

I would like to display Chinese characters in the console, with TrueType fonts and normal characters in Bitmap fonts. So far, I have succeeded in displaying:

1. ASCII TrueType, Unicode TrueType (via `XTerm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono Book` & `XTerm*faceNameDoubleSize: WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono`)
2. ASCII Bitmap, Unicode Bitmap (via `XTerm*faceName: Source Code Pro`)

I found #1 here (<insert-relevant-URL) and #2 via `$ fc-list :scalable=true:spacing=mono: family` which returns the scalable bitmap fonts that may be substituted for TrueType fonts.

Source Code Pro has support for Chinese characters. Although, I speculate third possibility, #3, ASCII Bitmap, Unicode TrueType. If a font is chosen without Chinese character support in the `faceName` resource and a fallback font in the `faceNameDoubleSize` resource, there would be different fonts displayed at the same time.

For some reason, only some Bitmap fonts are Truetype compatible. Why is this? For instance, in the command above, the default fixed font in XTerm is not returned because it is not scalable. If I specify `x:fixed` or `*-fixed-*-*-*-9-*` in `faceName` resource, and WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono in the `faceNameDoubleSize` resource, there is no presence of the default fixed font, all text has been replaced with Mono or sorts. Why must it be scalable? I just want to use the font as usual, and rely on another font for the unrecognized characters. It is really a simple request.

Summary: I want to specify a bitmap font, indiscriminately, for ASCII characters, as it is when you specify the font or `faceName` resource (without any following TrueType alternatives listed after since they supersede X fonts), then specify a supporting fallback font for unsupported Unicode characters - by `faceNameDoubleSize`, `wideFont` or whatever it is that I am missing.